# Unable to remove menu in development for Electron

Tags: electron

This is my createWindow function that I pass to app.on('ready')

```
function createWindow () {
    const startUrl = process.env.ELECTRON_START_URL || url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, '../index.html'),
        protocol: 'file:',
        slashes: true,
    })

    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
            width: 800,
            height: 600,
            webPreferences: {
            devTools: true,
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        },
    })

    mainWindow.loadURL(startUrl)
    mainWindow.removeMenu() // <----------------- HERE!
    mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
            mainWindow = null
    })
}
```

Pretty boiler plate the issue is that the mainWindow.removeMenu() does not work and it leaves it in places.

I've also tried `setMenu(null)` and the menu is still there.

Is the menu only removed in production, or am I doing something wrong?

**Edit**

I've also tried `mainWindow.setMenuBarVisibility(false)`, and it does not work as well.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are that you are still using an old version of Electron. There has been a bug preventing the removal of the menu bar for a long time. It has been fixed in [Electron 7.1.5](https://www.electronjs.org/releases/stable?version=7&page=2#7.1.5):

```
Release Notes for v7.1.5

Fixes

Fixed window menu unable to hide on startup. #21449
```

So, `mainWindow.removeMenu()` should work fine once you upgrade Electron to its latest version, or at least a version greater than or equal to `7.1.5`.